# Is there a way to compare two sets of dates that evaluates to a Truthy Falsy value using Karate framework?

Tags: javascript, api, automated-tests, karate

I am first making a POST API call that is feeding in an array of json using random dates.

From the response, I need to make sure that the dates that return are older than the dates I fed in.

I referred to documentation and decided to use the Self Validation Expressions (#? EXPR)

However, how can I use it to compare two sets of JSON arrays where the dates will not necessarily be in order?

```
  * def apiCall = call read(my_child_function_here_that_runs_steps) tableValues #tableValues = dates
  * def grabRecords = $apiCall[*].response #the return will be number format
  * def input = payload # payload = actual dates fed in
  * match each grabRecords.originalDates '#? _ >= input'
```

Would the above match statement work? If not, what can I change?